# Why am I getting an "Index out of bounds" error here? - Unity C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, indexoutofboundsexception

I get an "index out of bounds" error for the below code. I have commented the line at which the error occurs. This code is attached to a Gameobject consisting of a sequence of .obj files. It basically switches to the next consecutive .obj file in sequence on hitting play, thus making it appear as an animation. I am trying to flip through these .obj files, and on Raycasting, I am trying to obtain the vertices & normals at the hit point. Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

```
void Update()
{
    // on clicking the left mouse button
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(2))
    {
        // get the currently updated mesh
        meshRenderer = GetComponentInChildren<MeshRenderer>();
        meshCollider.sharedMesh = null;
        meshCollider.sharedMesh = mesh;

        // get mesh data
        vertices = mesh.vertices;
        normals = mesh.normals;
        triangles = mesh.triangles;

        // transform interpolated point from local to world space and set attached object to that position
        hitTransform = meshCollider.transform;

        //Ray cast done to identify point on human mesh(on mouse click) and assign sensor to the identified point
        Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
        RaycastHit hit;
           
        if (meshCollider.Raycast(ray, out hit, 200.0f))
        {
            // store index of the triangle (base index = index*3) and barycentric coordinates of the hitpoint
            Debug.Log("hit");
            triBaseIndex = hit.triangleIndex * 3;
            baryCenter = hit.barycentricCoordinate;

            v0 = vertices[triangles[triBaseIndex]];
            v1 = vertices[triangles[triBaseIndex + 1]];
            v2 = vertices[triangles[triBaseIndex + 2]];

        }

        interpolated_Position_v = v0 * baryCenter.x + v1 * baryCenter.y + v2 * baryCenter.z;

        float length_1 = Vector3.Distance(v0, interpolated_Position_v);
        float length_2 = Vector3.Distance(v1, interpolated_Position_v);
        float length_3 = Vector3.Distance(v2, interpolated_Position_v);
        
        if((length_1 > length_2) && (length_1 > length_3))
        {
            refIndex = triBaseIndex;
        }
        else if((length_2 > length_1) && (length_2 > length_3))
        {
            refIndex = triBaseIndex + 1;
        }
        else if((length_3 > length_1) && (length_3 > length_2))
        {
            refIndex = triBaseIndex + 2;
        }
    }

    // get triangle vertices
    p0 = vertices[triangles[triBaseIndex]]; //**THE ERROR POPS UP ON THIS LINE**
    p1 = vertices[triangles[triBaseIndex + 1]];
    p2 = vertices[triangles[triBaseIndex + 2]];

    // get normals at triangles vertices
    n0 = normals[triangles[triBaseIndex]];
    n1 = normals[triangles[triBaseIndex + 1]];
    n2 = normals[triangles[triBaseIndex + 2]];

    // interpolate position using the barycentric coordinate of the hitpoint to get accurate position within the triangle
    interpolatedPosition = p0 * baryCenter.x + p1 * baryCenter.y + p2 * baryCenter.z;
    // interpolate normals using the barycentric coordinate of the hitpoint & normalize it
    interpolatedNormal = (n0 * baryCenter.x + n1 * baryCenter.y + n2 * baryCenter.z).normalized;
    interpolatedPositionInWorldSpace = hitTransform.TransformPoint(interpolatedPosition);
    // determining the normal of the 3 vertices and assigning 
    interpolatedNormalInWorldSpace = hitTransform.TransformPoint(interpolatedNormal);
    right_vector = vertices[triangles[refIndex]] - interpolatedPosition;

    objectToAttach.transform.position = interpolatedPositionInWorldSpace;
```

Comment: What is `triBaseIndex`, what is `triangles[triBaseIndex]` and what's the length of each array? Use a debugger to inspect it while running if you do now know.

Comment: It is basically the same as the below code to obtain the vertices of the mesh triangle hit on raycasting -  Vector3 p0 = vertices[triangles[hit.triangleIndex * 3 + 0]];
        Vector3 p1 = vertices[triangles[hit.triangleIndex * 3 + 1]];
        Vector3 p2 = vertices[triangles[hit.triangleIndex * 3 + 2]];

Answer (score 0):

You are only setting a `vertices` and `triangles` if the mouse is pressed, and `triBaseIndex` only if the raycast hit. If the mouse was not pressed, or the raycast misses, there is no way to know what values these have, at least not from the given example. I would have guessed that much of the code sould only run if the raycast actually hit, I'm not sure what it is intended to do if the raycast misses..

Comment: Even on guarantee of a hit, I still get the error. I am trying to obtain the vertices and normals and attach another gameobject in that position.

Comment: @poojaB You said `vertices[triangles[triBaseIndex]]` caused the error, if the raycast hit you ran the exact same code earlier without an error. Unless you are mistaken about the failing line.

Comment: @PoojaB are you attaching gameobjects regardless if the mouse is pressed or you have a raycast hit? So if you the mouse is not pressed are you just attaching the same object over and over again to the same position? or adding a new object each frame?

Comment: so I just tried printing to see if the raycast even happens, and that is not even happening I realize. I am only attaching on a mouse click, and it is the same object placed in the same position through every frame until I click again on the mesh if I want to change the position.